# How to edit a HTML theme's mobile version?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I have downloaded a free HTML template from web and i'm trying to edit this HTML theme. In my theme i changed background photo, it's good on my computer and my resolution (1366x768) but on mobile  and other resolutions it's not working well. Background image is crushing.

please visit that website with your computer and your mobile phone for understanding clearly. [Theme link](http://www.odtusanayigunleri.org)

and please help me to edit mobile version of this website. I couldn't find anything. Here's the list of my javascript files in theme folder. [image of files](http://i.hizliresim.com/GpEnV3.jpg)

Comment: This theme is using bootstrap, you most likely need to make your edits for mobile in the css file.  There will be media queries where you can change/adapt your background for particular screens.

Not knowing exactly what you'd like to do, it's difficult to give you specific direction.

Answer (score 1):

What you can use is a media query the syntax of which looks like so:

```
@media <What to respond to> { 
    //then place the elements, class and id here
}
```

The media query can take in width by doing `@media (max-width:<insert width here>)` or `@media(min-width:<insert width here>)`

Multiple media queries can be used together like so `@media (max-width:100px) and (min-width:50px)`.

Another class of media queries can be used to specify how behave depending on the type of device, they include but not limited to:

- tv
- screen
- handheld
- all

They are used by typing `@media <name of device>`

An Example with some of they things i have mentioned being used

```
@media screen and (max-width: 100px) and (min-width: 50px) {
 //If the device is a screen, is wider/equal to 50px but smaller
 //than or equal to 100 then it will do this
img {
    width: 75px;
    height: 30px;} }
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) and (min-width: 101px) {
//I'm sure what will happen but i will tell you anyway
//If the device is a screen, is wider than/equal to 101px but
//smaller than/equal 400px
img { //Something
}}
```

My suggestion is to read up on it take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: I agree, try to change background (or picture in background) with media queries.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve your problem. One way is change the background using [media queries](http://cssmediaqueries.com/.). This is done by editing your css file. If you have multiple css files, you will need to know which one is setting your background image and place the media queries in there.